# how to remove a div on the basis of a class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this to remove the div whenever I call my `showresult();` function. I am dynamically creating this div `<div class="sampageswrapper">`, so this needs to be removed when ever `showresult()` is called.

```
function showresult(data) {
  jQuery('.sampageswrapper div').remove();
  // rest of my code.
}
```

But unfortunately this div is not removing.

```
<div class="sampageswrapper">
  <div id="image_div" class="img_class" name="image_div">
    ..........
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add a console.log("function called") to your showresult function to be sure the function gets called?

Comment: `$('.sampageswrapper').remove()`?

Comment: @Anton: thx i fixed the copy paste

Comment: your code will remove the first dive inside of samepageswrapper.  If you want to be more specific you can select the div by its id or lcass `'.samepageswrapper #image_div'` or `'.samepageswrapper .image_class'`

Comment: If you're creating the divs dynamically, are you sure your id's are unique?

Comment: @JonasGrumann: i am sure and i am creating same Div on an event again and again, so for sure i need to remove if it is already created.

Comment: Can you show us how do you call the showresult() method? Is there any chance that your code uses something like $('.class').click(showresult) and you're trying to use it on elements that are created dynamically? Because in this case you must use the jquery delegate() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the `.samepageswrapper` selector only

```
jQuery('.sampageswrapper').remove();
```

it should target that specific div.

when you use `.sampageswrapper div` as your selector, this targets all the div's inside the div element with `sampageswrapper` class

Comment: @zorac please see the question

Comment: i dont know what he intended while he was answering , but his solution is working

Comment: @kechu_vats "I am dynamically creating this div <div class="sampageswrapper">, so this needs to be removed"

Comment: I don't understand your downvote, I was explaining to him that it is his selector that is the problem?!

Comment: We all got confused by his selector, jQuery('.sampageswrapper div').remove(); we thought he wanted to remove the div inside the sampagewrapper. I revoked my downvote, sorry.

Comment: @Jonas Grumann No worries, I just got surprised with 3 instant down votes as I thought I understood his question :)

Comment: @noobie-php I hope my answer clears up the descendant selector issue for you. You can check out the jQuery [selector reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and more specifically Descendant Selector if you need more info